# deny already uploaded files in flask

Tags: python, flask

Hi I am uploading files with flask.
Somehow something recently broke and we want to deny already existing files. Which it used to do automatically. Now while adjusting the function I don't see it working somehow. I tried a couple things and I am stuck on this now. We do a curl request from another server and the upload is automated. We have a frontend on there but purely cause of the current state of the application what is relevant is that we list a directory and we want to forbid overwritting those files.

```
DENY_UPLOADED_IMAGES = os.listdir(f)  

@app.route("/upload")
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if 'file' in DENY_UPLOADED_IMAGES:
            flash('File already uploaded')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))

    return render_template('upload.html')
```

Comment: That `if 'file' in DENY_UPLOADED_IMAGES` doesn't check if YOUR file is in the list, only the string "file". Also you may update `DENY_UPLOADED_IMAGES` when you save a new file, `DENY_UPLOADED_IMAGES = os.listdir(f)` is executed only at server startup, you need to append the new filename

Comment: Also careful with filename and filepaths ;). Add some print during your programing to ensure it does what you expect

Comment: just tested with a print, somehow the directory seems empty so good suggestion. I am using the wrong method I actually want the upload loop to check if a file is present in that directory

Answer (score 1):

```
DENY_UPLOADED_IMAGES = os.listdir(f)
```

This, which is at the global level, only reads the list of currently uploaded files when your application is launched.  Filenames won't be added to this list if they were uploaded *since* the app (or worker) restarted.

Probably better to check each one at the time of upload:

```
        if os.path.exists(file.filename):
            flash('File already uploaded')
            return redirect(request.url)
```

This may still be open to a race condition if run with multiple WSGI workers.

Comment: I would have expected this to work too, somehow it doesn't

Comment: def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if os.path.exists(file.filename):
            flash('File already uploaded')
            return redirect(request.url)